# Why does Ruby convert integer to octal-escaped string instead of hex-escaped one?

Tags: ruby, string, type-conversion, hbase, jruby

I need:

```
"ff".hex.chr #=> "\xff"
```

but instead I get:

```
"ff".hex.chr #=> "\377"
```

Where is my mistake? What is missing? Environment is HBase 0.98.6 shell, which seems to be based on JRuby 1.6.8 console.

Comment: What version of Ruby do you use? Cause.. 2.1.4 :001 > "31ff".scan(/../).map { |x| x.hex.chr } => ["1", "\xFF"]

Comment: It's the same string in both cases - `"\377" == "\xff" #=> true`

Comment: Yes, string is the same. But why octal format is printed? This makes people confused. I need to calculate HBase row keys and print them... but they look different and people are getting afraid of this.

Comment: @RomanNikitchenko They're the same thing. If you print them, you'll get the same result. The only difference is what it looks like in the repl.

Comment: What's problem here? Both are valid representations of that character. If you need consistent hex output, you should be using `unpack`.

Comment: I think this is due to the format used by `String#inspect`. In 1.8.7 this uses the [`%03o` format](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/1.6.8/src/org/jruby/RubyString.java#L2416) (i.e. octal). In 1.9 and later the hex representation is used. If you’re able to start your JRuby console in 1.9 mode you might get the output you want (although that might have other effects you might not want). I don’t know how you’d do that with HBase, try setting the environment variable  `JRUBY_OPTS="--1.9"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"\xff"` and `"\377"` are different representations of the same data:

- `"\xff"` is hexdecimal, and is typical of newer Ruby versions.
- `"\377"` is octal, and is typical of older Ruby versions.

You can see how the same number produces different strings:

```
printf("%o",255) #=> "377"
printf("%x",255) #=> "ff"
```

The default representation is a typically due to your console settings and Ruby version.

In general, do not rely on `String#inspect` to produce a consistent  represenation, even on the same Ruby version. You can see this in action if you use some of the special characters:

```
"\007" #=> "\a"
```

The `String#inspect` method has altered the representation to neither octal nor hex.

If you're outputting to a system that requires a specific format, you can be explicit:

```
printf("\\x%x", 255) #=> \xff  # lower case
printf("\\x%X", 255) #=> \xFF  # upper case
```

You can also try the `pack` and `unpack` methods:

```
["ff"].pack("H*") #=> "\xFF"
```

If your string is always hex digits, and your desired output is just inserting "\x" in front of every two characters, then there's a fast solution:

```
print "a1b2c3".gsub(/../){"\\x#{$&}"}
#=> \xa1\xb2\xc3
```

A good quick introduction to Ruby string represenations and how to work with unprintable characters is in the [Safari Books Ruby Cookbook](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/ruby-cookbook/0596523696/ch01s05.html)

Comment: Thank you for couple of reasonable points especially for p`rintf()` - based solution but all of them has notable drawback - they result ALL characters converted but I'd like only non-printable. Finally I found all needed components.

Answer (score 0):

Lessons learned:

- Actually there was no any functional problem with octets. Just representation (thank to all comments and answers). Internally String content was the same.
- Yes, in Ruby 1.8 there was String#inspect with "%03o" format. And yes, HBase 0.98.6 uses this Ruby version for JRuby 1.6.8. This cannot be easily resolved in my case.
- Inspection has nothing to actual results so I have used Hbase `Bytes` class and prepared special `printer` for people who needs to see expected keys representation.

Here is the code which actually solves all my tasks including output that was wanted:

```
# Convert binary string to hex digits.
def bin_to_hex(s)
  s.each_byte.map { |b| b.to_s(16).rjust(2, '0') }.join
end

# Convers hex string to binary string.
def hex_to_bin(s)
  s.scan(/../).map { |x| x.hex.chr }.join
end

# HBase special 'convert and print' routine to get hex digits, process them and print.
def print_hex_to_bin(s)
  Kernel.print "\"" + Bytes.toStringBinary(s.scan(/../).map { |x| x.hex.chr }.join.to_java_bytes) + "\"\n"
end
```

Composed mostly based on http://anthonylewis.com/2011/02/09/to-hex-and-back-with-ruby/